# Make Python script combined with linux packages easy installable for end-user

Tags: python, linux, bash, installation

I wrote a python script that uses numpy, multiprocessing, tqdm and a feq other Python libraries. Additionally, I run packages (e.g. samtools, bwa, GATK) set are necessary to be installed in linux (apt-get install).

I'd like to somehow wrap all these dependencies up to make the final installation as user-friendly and stable as possible.

It seems as pip is not an option here as non-python-packages are included for my example.

Maybe Docker or creating a conda environment with all these dependecies might be possible but I did not really get how to manage this.

Comment: I would use bash script which uses `pip` to install python's modules and `apt` to install linux libraries.

Comment: in python you can use `subprocess` to run any program - it can be `apt-get` for all linux based on Ubuntu or `dpkg` for all linux based on Debian (even Ubuntu). I'm not sure  but Python should have also module to work directly with `apt`

Comment: yes that should work but I thought about a solution that is more encapsulated - if a version that somehow causes dependency conflicts is already installed your suggestions seem very unstable to me

Comment: What does your script do more or less? It might be well-suited for Docker (as you mentioned).

Comment: It is addressing a bioinformatical problem and uses samtools, bwa, GATK and maybe even more command-line tools. Additionally I make use of python's numpy, multiprocessing and pysam modules.

Until now it's not clear for me how to easily and  properly wrap these installations up in a docker image

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: You're talking to package your app as a `.deb` or `.rpm` package that holds all the references of the packages you want to install ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't go as far as installing software onto some computer/server because it might break other software running on that system. Instead, I would create a deb package and set dependencies on which software has to be installed to guide the user through installation.

**1. Create the deb directory structure**
The directory `deb` holds final scripts/binaries for the package. `source` has your python code.

```sh
$ cd $HOME/path/to/some/directory
$ mkdir -p ./deb/DEBIAN ./source
$ touch ./Makefile ./source/Makefile ./deb/DEBIAN/{control,preinst} ./source/hello-world.py
$ chmod +x ./deb/DEBIAN/preinst
```

**2. Add files**
Below I've added the content of every file. You should be able to implement it to your needs.

***./Makefile***: This file is responsible for generating the source and the deb.

```
PACKAGE         := hello-world

DEB_DIR         := deb
DEB_FILE        := $(PACKAGE).deb

SOURCE_DIR      := source
SOURCE_IN       := $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(PACKAGE).py
SOURCE_OUT      := $(DEB_DIR)/usr/bin/

.PHONY: all clean
all:
        @make -C $(SOURCE_DIR) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE)
        @mkdir -p $(SOURCE_OUT)
        @cp -r $(SOURCE_IN) $(SOURCE_OUT)
        @chmod -R a-s $(DEB_DIR)
        @dpkg-deb --build $(DEB_DIR) $(DEB_FILE)

clean:
        @rm -rf $(DEB_FILE) $(SOURCE_OUT)
        @make -C $(SOURCE_DIR) clean
```

***./deb/DEBIAN/control***: The control file for Debian's package manager.

```
Package: hello-world
Version: 1
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.24), python (>=2.7.13), virtualenv (>=1.11.6)
Maintainer: Your name <your-name@domain.org>
Description: This is a deb package to install an application
```

***./deb/DEBIAN/preinst***: The file in which you can install python packages. It is run before the installation of `hello-world.py`. Again, make sure you don't just (re)install/update a library. It could cause incompatibility problems in other software.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv/
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

***./source/Makefile***: A file I used to test this setup.

```
MYFILE=hello-world.py
all:
        @echo "#!/usr/bin/python\n\
        print('Hello world!')" > $(MYFILE)
        @chmod +x $(MYFILE)
clean:
        @rm $(MYFILE)
```

**3. Installation and removal**
Installing is very easy, just use `dpkg`.

```sh
dpkg -i hello-world.deb # for installation
dpkg -r hello-world     # for removal
```

A nice feature to have is you don't need to worry about versioning your software, since it's done in the `control` file. Debian has a pretty good [tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/Intro?action=show&redirect=IntroDebianPackaging) if you're interested in reading more.

EDIT:
Added `virtualenv` to example. Python packages should be installed in a virtual environment instead of globally.

Comment: `python-pip` should be a dependency, too, if you are using `pip`. And instead of `pip` installation, corresponding `apt` packages are preferred.

Comment: This is the only decent answer here IMO. Next step - spinning up a custom PPA :-) Actually, there was a nice project once called [`stdeb`](https://pypi.org/project/stdeb/) that extended `distutils` with commands for building the `deb`s from setup scripts, but is abandoned now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good starting point will be a Dockerfile, in which you start from an Ubuntu image and then install your desired dependencies(samtools, bwa) and also the python packages (placed in a requirements.txt)

- `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to have your desired python packages (numpy, tqdm etc)
- create a Dockerfile (which resides in the same directory as requirements.txt) e.g:

  ```
  FROM ubuntu:16.04

  RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get upgrade -y && \
  apt-get install -y python && \
  apt-get install -y wget \
  curl \
  bc \
  unzip \
  less \
  bedtools \
  samtools \
  openjdk-8-jdk \
  tabix \
  bwa\
  python-pip\
  software-properties-common && \
  apt-get -y clean  && \
  apt-get -y autoclean  && \
  apt-get -y autoremove

  RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

  WORKDIR /usr/srv/app

  COPY . /usr/srv/app

  RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

  CMD ["/bin/bash"]
  ```
- build your docker image `docker built --tag repository/imagename .` (DOT is the current directory)
- start image `docker run -dti --name test repository/imagename`
- enter in the container to start working `docker attach test`
- as you can see, I tested it and inside the container I have all the desired tools and packages
  [image]

---

- If you want to add new tools just add them in the Dockerfile and if you want to add python packages just expand the requirements.txt file.
- If you have a python script that does something and  you need to include it into the Docker container , just put it in the same directory with the Dockerfile and requirements.txt and update the Dockerfile (in order to have a container that starts your python script), more precisely in the Dockerfile the last line will be `CMD [ "python", "./my_script.py" ]`

Answer (score 0):

The most inclusive ways 3rd-party software uses in Linux is to provide a script (or a GUI frontend running a script) that runs all the necessary commands.

More preferrably, you can ship in a specific distribution's package format. That will ensure your dependencies are tracked on an ongoing basis by the system's package manager -- at the cost of being limited to a specific distribution (or a family of related distributions) and having to make sure your dependencies are also shipped in the same format and are available to the user.

Some distributions provide other ways that rely on additional subsystems present on the system; e.g. [Canonical offers a "snap" distribution format](https://snapcraft.io/store) that is run through the eponymous subsystem. The pros and cons here come from the fact that such environments isolate your program from the rest of the system: running in every place that the subsystem supports and not caring about package conflicts, at the cost of having to potentially bundle all the dependencies (thus losing free maintenance of them) and severe limits to what your program can use and interact with elsewhere on the system.